# How to compile C# code with Add-Type function in DEBUG mode

Tags: powershell

It's what i'm doing.

```
$ReferencedAssemblies = 
@(
    'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
    'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
    'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
)

$TypeDefinition = Get-Content -Path '$PSScriptRoot\Program.cs' -Raw
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDefinition -ReferencedAssemblies $ReferencedAssemblies
```

But the problem is i can't debug code compiled this way.

Comment: Use `-CompilerParameters`. (Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20925633/4137916), but in reverse.)

Comment: The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1) says "You cannot use the CompilerParameters and ReferencedAssemblies parameters in the same command". CompilerParameters has property for ReferencedAssemblies but it's incompatible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "incompatible".

Comment: I have referenced assemblies specified like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add-Type` command has internal method to resolve assemblies specified by `-ReferencedAssemblies` parameter. We can use it by reflection.

```
$addTypeCommand = Get-Command -Name 'Add-Type'
$addTypeCommandInstance = [Activator]::CreateInstance($addTypeCommand.ImplementingType)
$resolveAssemblyMethod = $addTypeCommand.ImplementingType.GetMethod('ResolveReferencedAssembly', [Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic, Instance')
$compilerParameters = New-Object -TypeName System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = '/debug-'

foreach ($reference in $ReferencedAssemblies)
{
    $resolvedAssembly = $resolveAssemblyMethod.Invoke($addTypeCommandInstance, $reference)
    $compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add($resolvedAssembly)
}

$compilerParameters.IncludeDebugInformation = $true
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDefinition -CompilerParameters $compilerParameters
```